# catch multiple route for single request

Tags: node.js, express

In my node.js app, I have one `router.get("/*)` route for handle all get request, expect dashboard. Which will be handled by `router.get("/dashboard")`. Now problem is `router.get("/*")` always called even if request route is `router.get("/dashboard")`. My code is given below:

```
 const express = require('express');
 const router = express.Router();

 // route for dashboard
 router.get("/dashboard", (req, res, next) => {
    res.render("index", { title: "dashboard"});
 })

 // this route will handle all get request
 router.get("/*", (req, res, next) => {

   res.render("index", {title: "index"})
})
```

Here when request is `router.get("/dashboard")`, both `router.get("/*)` and  `router.get("/dashboard")` are called. And first `router.get("/dashboard")` is called and then `router.get("/*)` is called.

All I want is that just ignore `router.get("/*)` when request come for `router.get("/dashboard")`.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: that is strange behavior. at one request only one of the callbacks will be triggered. how do you know both are getting called ?

Comment: @rdRahul, I have add some console.log on both route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `app.get("*")` will invoke always. Even if you try to invoke `app.get("*")`, you'll notice, that the method is invoking twice.
That's because, browser is trying to get a fevicon for your site.
if you console.log the `req.originalUrl`, you'll notice that, "/favicon.ico" is the additional call.

To solve this, you can either define a favicon for your site or disable it.

```
function ignoreFavicon(req, res, next) {
  if (req.originalUrl === "/favicon.ico") {
    res.status(204).json({ nope: true });
  } else {
    next();
  }
}

app.use(ignoreFavicon);
```

Comment: I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

In your catch all route would need to remove the `/`. It should look like this

```
router.get("*", (req, res, next) => {

   res.render("index", {title: "index"})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `app.get('*',`  and also you would need to put it after all other endpoints, something like this:

```
app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  ...
});

app.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
  ...
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  ...
});
```